# Unity lightweight render pipeline not working with ARCore

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, arcore

I use Unity 2018.3.11f1 (64-bit) + lwrp 4.10.0 with custom post processing effect + arcore.

- http://prntscr.com/nishjj
- http://prntscr.com/nisjfw
- http://prntscr.com/nisjp4
- http://prntscr.com/nisju6

I got black screen after unity logo when I build with uncheck "multithreaded rendering" in player settings.

With "multithreaded rendering" I get this.
https://ibb.co/THVqkS6

How do I fix it?.